# activesync with outlook2007

Tags: sync, gmail, microsoft-outlook-2007, activesync

I'm looking to "sync" my email/contacts/calander between gmail and my outlook07 client

I have an android phone which is the other side of the sync equation and its working pretty well

I just want the ability to put a contact in my phone and show up in outlook and visa versa 
(aka ill take alternatives to activesync as an answer if it fits the bill)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a F/OSS solution, but this software does exactly what you want, and has lots of configuration options to support most situations: http://www.daveswebsite.com/software/gsync/

The basic concept is that you install Gsync on your client computer where you run Outlook. You configure it with your Gmail login and it will create a two way sync between Outlook and Gmail. Then Gmail will be effective hub between your phone and your desktop.